# Table Background image in email

Tags: html, css, html-email

I'm having trouble with my background image not showing up in an emailer. Can anyone tell me why this would be happening.

```
   <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="489" width="638" align="left" background="http://www.bla.com/images/email-bg.jpg">
```

Here is the full setup with nested table for the text to overlay on top of the tables background image.

```
  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="489" width="638" align="left" background="images/email-bg.jpg">
     <tr>
            <td valign="top" align="left">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left" valign="top" width="100%" style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#585858; padding:35px 230px 0 40px">
                            <p style="font-size:28px; color:#474747">Welcome to <b>bla bla</p>
                            <p style="font-weight:bold; margin-bottom: 4px;">Just click the link below to finish your registration:</p>
                            <a href="#">Continue</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left" valign="top" width="100%" style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size:10px; color:#FFF; padding:80px 120px 0 40px">
                            <p style="margin-bottom:0">** Please do not reply to this automated message. The Email box that sent the message is not monitored.**</p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

**UPDATED CODE**

I changed my code to use this instead which uses style attribute

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="489" width="638" align="left" style="background-image:url(http://www.bla.com/images/email-bg.jpg)">
```

This works in apple mail client but not in outlook. 
Anyone know of any answers to outlook?

Answer (score 4):

Most of the e-mail clients dont show background images. Use solid colors. Or some workaround.

Comment: it's not really a workaround. You need to crop the image layout using Photoshop or Fireworks with the Slice Tool.

Comment: The image is one image. The problem isn't the image? or at least that what I thought. I thought it was the fact that outlook and some other email applications don't read background image.

Answer (score 2):

Background images on tables and table cells can not be rendered in Outlook 2007 and Outlook 2010.

use the vml hack

```
<td align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="border-bottom:1px solid #000; border-top:1px solid #000;" valign="middle" background="image_name.jpg">
<!-- EMAIL CONTENT STARTS HERE -->
                <!--[if gte mso 9]>
            <v:image xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" id="theImage" 

    style='behavior: url(#default#VML); display:inline-block; position:absolute; height:250px; width:600px; top:0; left:0; border:0; z-index:1;' src="image_name.jpg"/>
                <v:shape xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" id="theText" style='behavior: url(#default#VML); display:inline-block; position:absolute; height:250px; width:600px; top:-5; left:-10; border:0; z-index:2;'>
             <![endif]-->
    <table>
    <tr><td>CONTENT HERE</td></tr>

    </table>

<!-- EMAIL CONTENT ENDS HERE -->
                <!--[if gte mso 9]>
            </v:shape>
            <![endif]-->
```

Make sure height and width are correct and that should work

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
fill out the pertinent information in the code and place this where you want the image to be the background.

Answer (score -1):

Unless your base href is set your image path should contain the ENTIRE path (`http://domain/path`) since the email client does not know what domain you are referring to.